# Problemas guardando datos en estructura de árbol

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

¿Mi código no guarda una estructura en un árbol?

Es en C++. Cabe resaltar que soy nuevo en esto.

```
void inicializarAutomovil(automovil *aut)>inicializa automovil
{

    aut->precio = 0;

};


void leerAutomovil(automovil *&aut)>leer los datos para automovil
{

    system("cls");
    gotoxy(35,  5); cout<<"  REGISTRAR AUTOMOVIL  ";
    gotoxy(35,  6); cout<<"=======================";
    gotoxy(30,  7); aut->marca = leerTexto("Ingresa Marca: ");
    gotoxy(30,  8); aut->modelo = leerTexto("Ingrese Modelo: ");
    gotoxy(30,  9); aut->anio = leerTexto("Ingrese Anio: ");
    gotoxy(30, 10); aut->placa = leerTexto("Ingresa Placa: ");
    gotoxy(30, 11); aut->precio = leerEntero("Ingrese Precio: ");

};

nodoAutomovil *crearNodoAutomovil(automovil *&aut)>crea un nuevo nodo para automovil
{

    nodoAutomovil *newNodo = new nodoAutomovil();
    newNodo->aut = aut;
    newNodo->der = NULL;
    newNodo->izq = NULL;
    newNodo->numAut = 0;
    return newNodo;
    gotoxy(30, 17); cout<<"creando Nodo"<<endl;

};

void insertarAutomovil(nodoAutomovil *&arbol, automovil *&aut )>insertamos el automovil en arbol
{

    if ( arbol == NULL){

        nodoAutomovil *newNodo = crearNodoAutomovil(aut);
        arbol = newNodo;
        gotoxy(30, 16); cout<<"Nodo creado"<<endl;

    };

    else{

        int precioNew = arbol->aut->precio;

        if(aut->precio < precioNew){

            insertarAutomovil( arbol->izq, aut );
            gotoxy(30,17); cout<<"Nodo izquierda"<<endl;

        }else if (aut->precio > precioNew){

            insertarAutomovil( arbol->der, aut );
            gotoxy(30,18); cout<<"Nodo derecha"<<endl;

        } else{

            gotoxy(45 , 20); cout<<"NO SE PUDO REALIZAR LA OPERACION";

        };
    };
};

void registrarAutomovil(nodoAutomovil *arbol)>registrar ayudado de codigo anterior
{

    system("cls");
    automovil *aut = new automovil;
    inicializarAutomovil(aut);
    leerAutomovil( aut );
    insertarAutomovil( arbol , aut);
    gotoxy(35, 20); cout << " AUTOMOVIL REGISTRADO CON EXITO";
    gotoxy(40, 23); system("pause");

};

void mostrarListaAutomovil(nodoAutomovil *arbol)>muestro los automoviles registrado
{

    int x = 0;
    system("cls");
    nodoAutomovil *aux = new nodoAutomovil;

    aux = arbol;

    if(aux == NULL){

        gotoxy(30 , 5); cout<<"NO HAY AUTOMOVILES REGISTRADOS";
        gotoxy(30 , 6); system("pause");
        return;

    };

    if (aux->aut != NULL){

        gotoxy(20, 5 + x); cout<< aux->aut->marca;
        gotoxy(30, 5 + x); cout<< aux->aut->modelo;
        gotoxy(40, 5 + x); cout<< aux->aut->anio;
        gotoxy(45, 5 + x); cout<< aux->aut->placa;
        gotoxy(55, 5 + x); cout<< aux->aut->precio;
        x++;

    };

};

int main()>estructura principal
{

    nodoAutomovil *arbol = new nodoAutomovil();
    arbol = NULL;
    int opc;

    do{
        opc = menu();
        system("cls");
        switch( opc ){

            case 1: registrarAutomovil(arbol); break;
            case 2: mostrarListaAutomovil(arbol); break;
            case 3: /*buscarPlaca(arbol, mostrar)*/;break;
            case 4: /*mostrarAutoToyota(arbol, mostrar)*/;break;
            case 5: /*mostrarPrecioMenor(arbol)*/;break;
      };

    }while(!(opc == 6 ));

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Gracias por compartir todo tu código, pero necesitamos que nos expliques qué problema tienes, cómo reproducirlo y cuál es el comportamiento esperado.

Comment: "*¿Mi código no guarda una estructura en un árbol?*" tú sabrás, es tu código ó_Ò

Comment: Creo que tienes un error en la lógica de la función "insertarAutomovil", si el nuevo nodo a insertar es mayor que el elemento actual deberías pasar por parámetro el nodo derecho, en cambio, si es menor entonces pasas el nodo izquierdo, en tu código lo estás haciendo al revés.